# SQLiteDatabase. Store information in a list view

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I've been searching though this site for an answer I'm looking for and I can't find it. There are many good tutorial on YouTubes for SQLite Databases but none that really do what I want.

I'm making a game, and in the game I want players to be able to select an item they wish to purchase (from the shop) and when they purchase that item, it will be saved to the database. Then when they either go to their inventory or the "Sell" screen within the Shop, the listview will display what they have in their inventory.

I have the shop completely setup. I.e - The items they can purchase, when they select an item a dialoug pops up and asks if they want to buy it, if yes, it will subtract the gold they have and add the item to the database.

^ the only part that isnt working is the part where it adds the item to the database.

Here's some code:

```
String[] MeleeArmour = new String[] {

    "--- Melee Armour ---",

    "(100G) Bronze Helmet", "(250G) Bronze Chestplate",
            "(125G) Bronze Leggings", "(100G) Bronze Boots" //etc....
```

--

```
MeleeArmourList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            switch (position) {
            case 1:
                // (100G) Bronze Helmet

                AlertDialog.Builder dlgAlert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        Shop.this);
                dlgAlert.setMessage("Purchase Bronze Helmet?");
                dlgAlert.setTitle("Shop");
                dlgAlert.setPositiveButton("Buy",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                if (Integer.parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1
                                        .getText().toString()) >= 100) {
                                    int gold1 = Integer
                                            .parseInt(textViewShopGoldValue1
                                                    .getText().toString()) - 100;
                                    textViewShopGoldValue1.setText(""
                                            + gold1);
                                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Shop.this,
                                            "Bronze Helmet added to inventory",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    msg.show();

                                 //this is where I need to add the item to a database

                                } else {
                                    Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Shop.this,
                                            "You don't have enough gold!",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                    msg.show();
                                }
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setNeutralButton("View info",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                dlgAlert.setCancelable(false);
                dlgAlert.create().show();

                break;
```

Anyone have any ideas? How would I set up the database to work with what I want. Or is there a different method I could do? I tried doing a "putExtra" method in and saving the data, but after the player buys an item, i have to send them to the inventory screen, which is very annoying and people wouldn't enjoy that...

Comment: Your question is not answerable in the current state. What is stopping you from inserting in the database the item the user picked?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how. I'm looking for material that I can use to base what I want to do off of. Like creating a database that will work with a List View and pull the data.

Comment: @CoreyWilliams : Any database data can be made to work with a `ListView`. The `ListView` class uses an `Adapter` of some sort which basically 'glues' the source data (array, database etc) to the `ListView`. My advice would be to take a step back, do some basic `ListView` tutorials then look at `SQLiteOpenHelper` for creating/managing databases then look at `SimpleCursorAdapter` for querying your database and using it to populate a `ListView`.

Answer (score 0):

This involves some database design and application design.

You should have a table that stores the items that can be purchased. If you have that, then it's easy to display the items available for purchase, and their cost, and you can distribute the database with your app in various ways.

Next, you need a table that stores the items that a user has purchased.

Now, to purchase an item, a user goes to the purchase activity. You check the user's balance, query the items table for items that the user can purchase, and display this in a list view. The user clicks an item, you deduct the cost from the user's balance, and store the item in the user's inventory view.

A "confirm" isn't necessary. Instead, have an "undo" or "remove" option.